# MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload

Tags: javascript, error-handling, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to send a transaction using the ethereum API and metamask. However, whenever I try, I get the error
`MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":2336617090279,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf88f08843b9aca008252089467bcbfe92a7ec5e00dee9e 37735a10ad0044567b80ac30787b2266 6e616d65223a224d6165656e222c2263657274223a225072657369 64656e74206177617264227d2ca081241ac03d1f83b0fff6e5afe73b5d3095fc9a79a3735098a9c29c730275ba59a07dc9a441730c0f512c0eb47c52d78d85e8d1346d0e88b9dfef4fe6632e53c869"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]`

Does anybody know why?

Comment: did you find a solution?